# will living in the clouds rain problems for my t1?

Tags: bandwidth

I am thinking of moving some users into mostly cloud based applications.  Anyone seen an good numbers on bandwidth demand per user?  will moving 12 people to the cloud cost me twice as much in new t1's as it saves?

Comment: Apart from being poorly worded, this question cannot be answered because there is no detail upon which an answer can be based. It's a bit like asking if 12 people will fit inside a box, without telling us anything about the people or the box. As for cost, that's too localised.

Comment: Well, he may just be ignorant of what he needs to ask. From the way the title is worded, I'm not sure if he's being cutesy but confused, or a troll of some sort.

Comment: I love the title, though.

Comment: I honestly expected it to be a question about ambient moisture affecting his physical T1, which I've seen before.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this yourself if you know:

1. How much bandwidth per user a given application is going to use
2. How many users are going to be using each application
3. What your current average unused bandwidth on your current T1 is

if Sum(1 X 2) (over all new applications) is greater than 3, then yes, you will need more bandwidth. Or see if you can find and decrease any non-business activities that are soaking up bandwidth.